# How to calculate the integral for an independent variable for a regression equation

Tags: integration, regression

Hi I have a panel dataset (for 35 years and 200 panels). For a project I need to estimate a regression of the following form.

$Y_{it} = Y_{it-1}+[\int_{u∈i}\int_{min(T_{uz})}^{max(T_{uz})}⁡h_i(T_{uz})dT_{u}d_{u}]$

Where Y is the dependent variable (denoting total production) and T is the independent variable (denoting temperature deviations during a period z within a longer time period t (i.e. ∈)) for a production unit u within a larger unit i (i.e. ∈).
My problem is while I have run linear regressions in the past, I have not dealt with an independent variable that is an integral. 
I have the data for my temperature variable and need to know how I can calculate this variable?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please rewrite the equation. As you can see, it's a complete mess as it currently stands ...

Comment: Thank you. I have rectified the equation.